# UK Ancestry Visa

Tags: uk-visa

I am trying to find the UK Ancestry Visa on the UK.GOV website. Is it a Right of Abode certificate of Entitlement Visa? Step by step where to go would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. Type "uk ancestry visa" into your nearest search engine. That leads me directly to https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa
2. Start at https://www.gov.uk, click on "Visas and immigration", then "Work visas" (yes this is not obvious), then "UK Ancestry visa".

Comment: Then where?.I can get to there its from there that I am lost

Comment: There's a "Next" button at the bottom of the page that goes to the next page. Or, you can move between the pages using the numbered links at the top.